# Get the current logged in user in MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to fetch the current logged in username for a databasequery in C# and trying to find a C# version of the ASP "command" **User.Identity.Name**. When I'm googling it I only find people that's fetching the Windows username with **Environment.Username** and similiar solutions - which is not what I need.

So, I'm speaking of the accounts made from the ASP Configuration dialog in VS, or the auto-generated register functions. I can register/login/logout and everything, so I'm guessing there is some sort of session that's storing the info I need. I just don't know where I can find it.

I hope I'm not that confusing :) Anyone know how to fetch my session-info from a C# model?

Comment: Are you using Asp.Net membership provider?

Comment: Have you actually tried `User.Identity.Name`? What does it give you? (the entire namespace is `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`)

Comment: and does you app require logins? if not then you obviously won't get a useful Identity.Name

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to ASP.NET so I don't know. I've a Membership provider defined in Web.config and that's autogenerated. I also get a row in Membership for each user created during my debugs so I guess I do. However, I don't reach any Membership classes other than AccountMembershipService from where I'm typing and that class don't have what I want. So, I think I am but I'm not sure! :)

Comment: I think my problem was a namespace related one. I seem to reach it if I use the whole namespace Mansfield posted.

Comment: @Thomas Excellent. I'll add an answer explaining. EDIT: Added. Be sure to mark as answer and upvote if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the name of the current user in MVC the same way as you can in classic ASP, with `User.Identity.Name`. The whole namespace is `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`.

Without seeing your code I can't be sure, but I imagine you aren't including `System.Web`, and even if you are you may need to specify `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I had a User object I was refering to when I was using my last prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass Controller property "User" to your model.
something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IndexModel model = new IndexModel(this.User);
}
```

Comment: don't forget that you can always access System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User

Comment: Thank you, I did not know this. I cant give it thumbs up yet, cause I'm lack some reputation still. But it was helpful!